# Reversing DALY BMS BLE protocol

Tags: protocol, bluetooth

I am trying to communicate with the DALY BMS (Battery management system) via BLE.

I was wondering if anyone has any bit of information regarding their protocol, something to start with?

Comment: Have you checked their Android app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inuker.bluetooth.daliy Bluetooth communication recording is built-in in on most Android devices (check developer menu).

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this Python library](https://github.com/dreadnought/python-daly-bms) for reference. It doesn't work for all commands, but you'll have the basics.

The Daly BMS (at least mine) uses this [TTL-to-Bluetooth dongle](https://fccid.io/2AD56HLK-B20/User-Manual/User-Manual-4865748.pdf). It will basically allows you to send UART commands over bluetooth, convert them to actual serial data and send back the answer over bluetooth as well.

The Daly UART protocol is [here](https://diysolarforum.com/resources/daly-smart-bms-manual-and-documentation.48/).

Comment: I sniffed the BLE comm and it seems not to be a 1-to-1 message that goes over BLE (as it is on RS-485 or CANbus). I am currently mocking the peripheral and when I connect the Daly BMS app to my peripheral, I got a "Request MTU failed" fro the app. I need to pass this before I can dump the data. Any idea?